# Is there a comparison between these two functions?

Tags: real-analysis, functions, convex-analysis

Given a **convex** function $f$ from $R^2$ to $R$ which **vanishes** on $(0,1)$ and on $(1,0).$ Put $g(x,y)=1-x-y,$ where $(x,y) \in R^2.$
Which of these functions is less than the other $f(x,y)\leq g(x,y)$ or $f(x,y)\geq g(x,y)$ for $x,y$ in $]-\infty,0],$ $[0,1]$ and $[1+\infty[.$

**Edit:** $f$ is a decreasing function and $f$ is negative if $x,y > 1$ and $f$ is positive if $x$ and $y$ are $ < 1.$
Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by *compare*?

Comment: I mean which of these functions is less than the other $f(x,y)\leq g(x,y)$ or $f(x,y)\geq g(x,y)$ for $x,y$ in $]-\infty,0],$ $[0,1]$ and $[1+\infty[.$

Comment: I think it's not possible without further assumptions: Choose $f(x,y) = 2g(x,y)$ and $f(x,y) = 1/2 g(x,y)$.